# Changing the Title to a House

Tags: real-estate, ohio, ownership, restraining-orders

A friend and I bought a fixer-upper house. I paid in full for it. She was supposed to pay for all repairs, and made many other promises. She said she would have income from a settlement for 7 years that would cover the repair. Because of this, I put her name on the title. Huge mistake, of course.

She has broken every promise. She lied about the income. She has started drinking and abusing drugs, which she had not done for many years (I didn't know her when she did). She also tells me she has a prison record for assault. She has hoarded out the house. And now she says that she paid for the house, and lets me live here out of pity because I'm a "cripple". (I am permanently disabled). She has started threatening me with physical harm and with having me put in a nursing home. She told me that if I try to evict her, she will get 30 days to get out, and will spend them making me wish I was never born, and it will be her word against mine. She told me she screams at me hoping I have a heart attack and die. She tells me she is going to force me out of my home. It is a complete change in personality and character. I suspect incipient dementia in combination with the huge amounts of alcohol. She is smoking marijuana, taking pills, and using LSD, which is NOT OK with me. She is 59 years old.

She has also moved an unemployed man in with her. I was not consulted, or even properly introduced. They drink huge amounts of beer. She was contributing toward expenses and food, cut way back, then paid nothing. Now she is giving me only $40 or $50 a week for all expenses for two people.

She has no proof whatsoever of anything she says, other than that she, at one point, had a sum of money almost equal to the final price of the house. I have ample proof that I paid for the house, including bank records. I have no contract with her, but I do have witnesses to her promises. I pay the property taxes. All utilities are in my name, and paid by me out of my account. I buy almost all of the food on my debit card.

I don't feel safe here. She may attack me. She might just burn the place down falling asleep while smoking. Is there any way for me to have her name taken off the deed, and have her and her hoard (which is damaging the hoarded rooms) removed from the house, and get a restraining order due to the threats? Or do I have to pay for the horrible mistake of trusting a friend of many years?

Sorry this is so long.

Comment: You'll most likely have to sue your friend to gain sole ownership of the house.  I doubt you can evict her if her name is on the title.  You might get better results from this site if you separate your questions.  For example, the question of whether she can allow someone to live in the house over your objections is separate from the question of whether you can gain sole ownership of the house.  Another possible approach would be to get her arrested for drug use, but that would most likely put you in even more peril than you already are.

Comment: You should consult an attorney.

Comment: You need to speak to a lawyer. Immediately. (After finding somewhere safer to be temporarily.) This question should be closed. I am sorry this has happened to you and wish you the best of luck in solving this problem, but you need real legal advice so you can take action and we cannot provide it here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal advice.

Comment: This is a very unfortunate but specific situation that requires legal advice, which cannot be provided here (see, for example, http://meta.law.stackexchange.com/q/13/10), but which I hope you can find pro bono through public or legal aid agencies.